# How to add array list with Doubles

Tags: java

My assignment asks for me to add items to a shopping cart, asking the user for input. We are to use the add method but I keep getting an error. I have tried this for days, I have also searched the web and can't find an answer I understand.

```
List<Double> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
shoppingCart.add(" "); 
double shoppingCartItem; 
shoppingCartItem = numberReader.nextDouble(); 
for (int counter = 0; counter <shoppingCart.size(); counter++) {
   System.out.print("Item"); 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I am extremely new to java.

I realized what I was trying to do may not have been clear. This is how the completed program should look. I have been working on this for days. Any direction would be so appreciated. I am at a lost, everything I've done has made this worst.

![enter image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yhyg.png)

Comment: You are trying to add a string to a list of doubles, that's the first error

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you expect to get from the user as input. The name of the item? The price? Both? Show us the workflow you expect the user to go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add(obj)` function will add the given object to the list. So you should add your double variable to it. You **don't** need to add an 'empty' element beforehand (which is what I assume you were tying to do with the empty string?) 
E.g

```
ArrayList<Double> shoppingCart = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
double shoppingCartItem; 
shoppingCartItem = numberReader.nextDouble(); 
shoppingCart.add(shoppingCartItem); 
for (int counter = 0; counter <shoppingCart.size(); counter++) {
    System.out.print("Item"); 
}
```

Although it might be intimidating at first, its always a good idea to have a read of the docs when working with Classes and functions you arn't familiar with. For example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) is information about the add() method.

And I'm guessing you'll probably want to use the retrieve the doubles in your list at some point, so have a read of the `get()` method.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am making a shopping cart program to add items to a cart, store the items, ask the user if they would like to delete an item and then producing a total. I just can't seem to get this program up and running.

Comment: What part is not working? What error messages to you get? The above code should wait for you to enter a double (eg. 12.52) and then print the word 'Item'. It will then be a very small change to make it print the number you just entered (hint use ArrayList's `get()` method). And then have a read of the docs, and see if you can find a way to delete items from the list.